# Convert object that contains another object to json

Tags: java, javascript, json

I need to pass data from `HTML` to `Service` using `JSON` (in `JS/JQUERY`)

In the service I have a service call that reciving an object that contains another object and 2 more fields.

Role object:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Role implements Serializable {           
    private long id;
    private String name;    
}
```

User object:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class User implements Serializable {           
    private String userName;
    private String password;    
    private ArrayList<Role> roles;
}
```

Till now I managed to pass data to `JSON` like that to other service: (data that contains only 2 parameters: id and userName )

```
xmlHttp.open("POST", "http://www.foo.com/serviceFunction2", true);
xmlHttp.send('{"Id": "123", "userName": "test"}');
```

So, my question is how can I fill the **User** object that contains the **Role** object using  `JS/JQUERY`? like I managed to send it with this line:

```
xmlHttp.send('{"Id": "123", "userName": "test"}');
```

Thanks

Comment: Use a JSON library, such as JAXB, GSON, Jackson, etc.

Comment: @Matt Ball - I need to convert it in the `HTML` code...

Comment: What? Your question does not make sense. I assume you mean "JavaScript," not "HTML." What is "it" that you need to convert?

Comment: @Matt Ball - I meant that in the `HTML` code I need to pass the **user**  object using 'JS/JQUERY'. like I managed to pass Regular types
with xmlHttp.send('{"Id": "123", "userName": "test"}'); Now I need to pass an object that contains object...

Comment: If you're using jQuery (as tagged) why code your own `xmlHttp` stuff? Just use `$.ajax()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to "nest" objects in JS, but for your purpose probably the simplest is to nest your object and/or array literals. If "roles" is supposed to be an array, then something like this:

```
'{"userName":"test", "password":"secret", "roles":["role1","role2","role3"]}'
```

If each role in the array is itself an object with properties:

```
{
   "userName":"test",
   "password":"secret",
   "roles": [
       { "roleName":"role1", "prop2":"someValue", "prop3":"whatever" },
       { "roleName":"role2", "prop2":"someValue", "prop3":"whatever" },
       { "roleName":"role3", "prop2":"someValue", "prop3":"whatever" }
   ]
}
```

(Line breaks added for readability, but you'd remove them if creating a string.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your goal is but if you are using the HTML page as a GUI and Java for the processing you might as well use [jsf](/questions/tagged/jsf) or similar. There are multiple frameworks like [primefaces](/questions/tagged/primefaces), [myfaces](/questions/tagged/myfaces) or [icefaces](/questions/tagged/icefaces) that handle a lot of stuff for you.

Have a look at the [Primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/home.jsf) if you're interested.

As MattBall suggested you can also use something like [jaxb](/questions/tagged/jaxb), this takes a lot of load off your hands.

You can use a lot of powerful and easy stuff.

You can map objects to JSON/XML using annotations:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Role
{
    @XmlAttribute
    private long id;
    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;    
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class User
{
    @XmlAttribute
    private String userName;
    @XmlAttribute
    private String password;
    @XmlElement    
    private ArrayList<Role> roles;
}
```

You can then use this in a web service:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("user/{username}")
public User getUser( @PathParam("username") String userName)
{
    User user;
    // Get your user
    return user;
}
```